# Filtering the object of a type with OfType in C#

Tags: c#, linq, oftype

I have a base class Base, and class A/B that inherits from it.

```
public class Base
{
    int x;
}
public class A : Base
{
    int y;
}
public class B : Base
{
    int z;
}
```

I tried to use OfType to filter the only object that I need as follows:

```
public static void RunSnippet()
{
    Base xbase; A a; B b;
    IEnumerable<Base> list = new List<Base>() {xbase, a, b};
    Base f = list.OfType<A>; // I need to get only the object A
    Console.WriteLine(f);
}
```

When I compiled the code, I got this error:

> error CS0428: Cannot convert method group 'OfType' to non-delegate type 'Base'. Did you intend 
>       to invoke the method?

What's wrong with the code?

Comment: It is a method, you forgot the parentheses.  OfType<A>().

Comment: Try traversing through your list and check each one againt a type using typeof. Array lists let you store ant type of object.

Comment: @user1260028: The OP's approach will work just fine, if he uses the method correctly. There's *definitely* no need to start using non-generic collections (urgh).

Comment: Was just a suggestion. Good point. However you will be surprised how well generic collections can clean up long code if done right.

Comment: @user1260028: Um, I'm happy using generic collections. You're the one suggesting using a *non-generic* collection (`ArrayList`)... and I can't remember the last time I found a situation where `ArrayList` would be better than using `List<T>`, aside from contexts where generics weren't available at all.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There are two problems:

- `OfType` returns `IEnumerable<T>`, not `T`
- It's a method - you forgot the brackets

Perhaps you wanted:

```
Base f = list.OfType<A>().FirstOrDefault();
```

?

Answer (score 2):

Brackets ?

This is a function and not operator.

```
Base f = list.OfType<A>()
```

Check out the reference:

[Enumerable.OfType(Of TResult) Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx)