# Linq query to select properties only of type?

Tags: c#, linq

I have an `IEnumerable` of `MyItem` which contains a property called `MyProperty`, which can be of several types.

I want an `IEnumerable` of all `MyProperty` objects of a specific type. Is there a single linq command to do this?

I've tried

```
myItems.Where(mi => mi.MyProperty is MyType).Select(li => li.MyProperty as MyType)
```

or

```
myItems.Select(mi => mi.MyProperty as MyType).Where(mp => mp != null)
```

or

```
myItems.Select(mi => mi.MyProperty).OfType<MyType>()
```

All seem a bit convoluted. Is there a simpler command to do this?

Comment: `myItems.Select(z => z.MyProperty).OfType<MyType>()` - your last option - is the best option. It is clear that you are asking for a specific property, then filtering on a specific type. You can't do that in one operation. _You could write an extension method to do both at once if you want to._

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filtering the object of a type with OfType in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165660/filtering-the-object-of-a-type-with-oftype-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Can `MyProperty` be null?

Comment: @vc74 improbable, but if possible I should cover the case.

Comment: @JohnoBoy You can't cover that case. Anything that is `null` doesn't have a type so can't be returned (i.e. any solution you come up with will filter out `null`s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up using

```
myItems.Select(mi => mi.MyProperty).OfType<MyType>()
```

As comments suggested it is the best option.