# display list items into data grid view c#

Tags: c#, list, datagridview

I have a super-class (abstract) and then 2 inherited classes. 
SuperClass: Sessions 
Class 1: Cycling 
Class 2: Running

I also have a list that will hold all of my objects 
 `private List<Session> allSessions = new List<Session>();`

I also have declared some arrays that hold hard-coded data to populate my objects.

Also, Running and Cycling has an overridden `ToString()` method that displays different data depending on the class.

```
public override string ToString() => $"Cycle Average RPM is {AverageRpm} and Average Resistance is {AverageResistance}";
```

I am using a for loop to create and add new objects into my list like this

```
            for (int i = 0; i < id.Length; i++)
            {
                Cycling Cycle = new Cycling(id[i], titles[i], date[i], duration[i], difficulty[i], instructor[i],
                    description[i], averageRpm[i], averageResistance[i]);

                // Add new objects to list
                allSessions.Add(Cycle);
            }
```

I have a dataGridView that is getting everything from my list and displays it like this:
[image]

My problem now is, that I want to display only specific data depending on what you choose in the ComboBox, but something is not working,

The overridden `ToString()` is not added to the list for some reason and whenever I choose a different option from the ComboBox, nothing is being displayed.

EDIT 1:

```
            // Filter Sessions by type using Linq
        var sessions = new List<Session>();
        var cyclingSessions = sessions.OfType<Cycling>();
        var runningSessions = sessions.OfType<Running>();

        listBox1.DataSource = null;
        listBox1.Items.Clear();


        if (cboMenu.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            // Populate GridView with data
            dataDisplay.DataSource = allSessions;
        }
        else if (cboMenu.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {
            // Populate GridView with data
            dataDisplay.DataSource = cyclingSessions;
        }
        else
        {
            // Populate GridView with data
            dataDisplay.DataSource = runningSessions;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to create a filtered `allSessions` and set that collection as your data source. Right now nothing you have in code is filtering you're allSessions list and your trying to set the data source for every individual item which isn't going to work.

Comment: @JSteward and how I can do the filtering of the list.
It has to be filtered by the type of the object?
e.g Cycling and Running?

Comment: Something like [filter by type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165660/filtering-the-object-of-a-type-with-oftype-in-c-sharp)

Comment: In your edited code `sessions` is an empty list are you initializing it before filtering?

Comment: I have already this `private List<Session> allSessions = new List<Session>();`

Comment: right that's an empty list with no data

Comment: I am populating it using my for loop if you see the code above.

Comment: well your code shown is conflicting in one part your adding to `allSessions` and then your filtering `sessions` which has no data. So the code you've posted paints a conflicting picture of what you're doing. You should be filtering `allSessions` not `sessions`

Comment: Like that? `var cyclingSessions = allSessions.OfType<Cycling>();`

Comment: yes like that, should be what you're after

Comment: And then set the data source like this:`dataDisplay.DataSource = cyclingSessions;`?
Nothing happened.

Comment: @JSteward this is what i get back System.Linq.Enumerable+<OfTypeIterator>d__95`1

Comment: Yes you have to enumerate the result to get a collection, try calling `ToList()` on the result

Comment: Working fine now, thanks.

Comment: Yeah the grid view is only going to bind to properties of the data, instead of overriding ToString you could just make a new property and display that as a column in your grid view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to filter your sessions list and set that as your data source you can easily filter the list using `OfType` from `System.Linq` It would look something like this:

```
var sessions = new List<Sessions>();
var cyclingSessions = sessions.OfType<Cycling>();
var runningSessions = sessions.OfType<Running>();
dataDisplay.DataSource = cyclingSessions;
```

Comment: and then how I will implement that into my ComboBox?

Comment: When the combobox changes set your datasource to a filtered sessions collection.

Comment: Like this?

`            if (cboMenu.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
                // Populate GridView with data
                dataDisplay.DataSource = allSessions;
            }
            else if (cboMenu.SelectedIndex == 1)
            {
                // Populate GridView with data
                dataDisplay.DataSource = cyclingSessions;
            }
            else
            {
                // Populate GridView with data
                dataDisplay.DataSource = runningSessions;
            }`

Comment: I don't get anything back

Comment: Not yet. I will update the question with my code for you to see.