# C#: How to get the value of derived class from an IReadOnlyList containing abstract classes

Tags: c#

Hi how can I return the first ValueNode's value + the value of the first value in the first ListNode?

Node is the parent abstract class.

ListNode is a derived class containing a list of ValueNodes.

ValueNode is the derived class containing the value.

```
public static readonly IReadOnlyList<Node> TestData = new List<Node>
        {
            new ValueNode {Value = "a"},
            new ListNode
            {
                Values = new List<Node>
                {
                    new ValueNode {Value = "b"},
                    new ValueNode {Value = "c"},
                    new ListNode
                    {
                        Values = new List<Node>
                        {
                            new ValueNode {Value = "d"},
                            new ValueNode {Value = "e"}
                        }
                    },
                    new ListNode
                    {
                        Values = new List<Node>
                        {
                            new ValueNode {Value = "f"}
                        }
                    },
                    new ValueNode {Value = "g"}
                }
            },
            new ValueNode {Value = "h"},
            new ValueNode {Value = "i"},
            new ListNode
            {
                Values = new List<Node>
                {
                    new ValueNode {Value = "j"},
                    new ValueNode {Value = "k"}
                }
            },
        };
        public abstract class Node
        {
            protected object Data;
        }
        public class ValueNode : Node
        {
            public string Value
            {
                get => (string)Data;
                set => Data = value;
            }
        }
        public class ListNode : Node
        {
            public List<Node> Values
            {
                get => (List<Node>)Data;
                set => Data = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to know how I could return the value 'a' and the value of 'b' from TestData.

Comment: You need some form of a walk method.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Essentially, I tried to access the list with various indexing, however i constantly run into the error of: ' Cannot implicitly convert type Program.Node to Program.Valuenode. I'm not sure what to additionally try

Answer (score 0):

you could use a **linq** expression to [filter for elements with a given type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165660/filtering-the-object-of-a-type-with-oftype-in-c-sharp):

```
IReadOnlyList<Node> testData = new List<Node> { new ValueNode(), new ListNode() };
var valuesOnly = testData.OfType<ValueNode>().ToArray();
```

which is equivalent to:

```
var valuesOnly = testData.Where(x => x is ValueNode).ToArray();
```